# How to change only one image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image with two small image/buttons on top of it. Each image/button should change the main image to either the original image or to the alternative image. I have a small javascript function to make it work. But the problem comes when I want to have 2+ images with the same functionality on the same page. The button changes all images at once. Is there a simple solution so that the JS only changes the image within the DIV in which the button is pressed?

HTML:

```
    <div class="mobile-product-image-switcher">
      <img src="main-image.jpg" alt="" class="mobile-product-switcher-image" />
      <img src="switcher-button-1.jpg" alt="" class="switcher-button-1" onclick="changeImg('main-image.jpg')" />
      <img src="switcher-button-2.jpg" alt="" class="switcher-button-2" onclick="changeImg('main-image-2.jpg')" />
    </div>

<div class="mobile-product-image-switcher">
      <img src="main-image-3.jpg" alt="" class="mobile-product-switcher-image" />
      <img src="switcher-button-1.jpg" alt="" class="switcher-button-1" onclick="changeImg('main-image-3.jpg')" />
      <img src="switcher-button-2.jpg" alt="" class="switcher-button-2" onclick="changeImg('main-image-4.jpg')" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-product-image-switcher {
  position: relative;   
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mobile-product-switcher-image {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.switcher-button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switcher-button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
function changeImg(src){
    $('.mobile-product-image-switcher img.mobile-product-switcher-image').attr('src', src);}
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to send the button element to the function from the click event handler defined inline on the element. You can do that by including `this`, which references the source element of the event. Then you can scope the image selector to that element and only alter the relevant one.

Comment: @TravisJ Hey, thank you. Can you please help with where I should add `this` in the code? I'm usually only using HTML/CSS so I don't know how to add it to JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small example of what Travis J commented in your question

```js
function changeImage(src, context) { 
  context.parentElement.querySelector(".image")
    .setAttribute("src", "https://dummyimage.com/150/fefefe/888&text=" + src);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/150/fefefe/888&text=1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80/fefefe/888&text=1" onclick="changeImage('1', this)">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80/fefefe/888&text=2" onclick="changeImage('2', this)">
<div>

<div>
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/150/fefefe/888&text=3">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80/fefefe/888&text=3" onclick="changeImage('3', this)">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80/fefefe/888&text=4" onclick="changeImage('4', this)">
<div>
```

Edit: You may have to do a few changes, as I'm not using jQuery in this example and I'm also adding a prefix to the src (just for the example).